# What's the right way to do an initial load of list data in Firebase and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

Every firebase client example I see in Swift seems to oversimplify properly loading data from Firebase, and I've now looked through all the docs and a ton of code. I do admit that my application may be a bit of an edge case.

I have a situation where every time a view controller is loaded, I want to auto-post a message to the room "hey im here!" and additionally load what's on the server by a typical observation call.

I would think the flow would be:
1. View controller loads
2. Auto-post to room
3. Observe childAdded

Obviously the calls are asynchronous so there's no guarantee the order of things happening. I tried to simplify things by using a complete handler to wait for the autopost to come back but that loads the auto-posted message twice into my tableview.

```
    AutoPoster.sayHi(self.host) { (error) in
        let messageQuery = self.messageRef.queryLimited(toLast:25).queryOrdered(byChild: "sentAt")
        self.newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let m = Message(dict, key: snapshot.key)
                    if m.mediaType == "text" {
                        self.messages.append(m)
                    }
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Worth noting that this seems very inefficient for an initial load. I fixed that by using a trick with a timer that will basically only allow the collection view to reload maximum every .25s and will restart the timer every time new data comes in. A bit hacky but I guess the benefits of firebase justify the hack.

I've also tried to observe the value event once for an initial load and then only after that observe childAdded but I think that has issues as well since childAdded is called regardless.

While I'm tempted to post code for all of the loading methods I have tried (and happy to update the question with it), I'd rather not debug what seems to not be working and instead have someone help outline the recommended flow for a situation like this. Again, the goal is simply to auto-post to the room that I joined in the conversation, then load the initial data (my auto-post should be the most recent message), and then listen for incoming new messages.

Comment: All sounds fair. What's your question? Or alternatively: what is not working in the code that you shared?

Comment: Specifically in the code I posted, I get a duplicate row for the auto-post. We could go the debugging route or I was hoping someone should share some code or pseudo-code for posting and immediately loading a list in this situation

Answer (score 0):

**Instead of**

```
self.newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
```

**try replacing with**

```
let childref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("ChildName")
childref.queryOrdered(byChild:"subChildName").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
```

Comment: No dice - still get the auto post twice